# Webstorm 10 lodash methods "private member not accessible" warning

Tags: webstorm, lodash

I've just started using WebStorm 10 EAP and all my lodash methods are highlighted with a warning "Private member is not accessible". I do have `bower_components` folder that has `lodash`added as a library. Is there anything special I need to do to to fix this warning, since these methods are available to call?

Comment: I've got the same error, must be a WebStorm bug since it's early access.

Comment: Getting same error in WebStorm 10.0

Comment: Same here in the release version of WS 10, it's definitely an inspection issue and not a LINTER issue.  If you haven't already, please file a bug with JetBrains:  https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/home

Comment: This is a known issue and currently being tracked at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15455. Please vote for it there if you'd like to see it fixed soon.